# How to read a sql file in flutter, for android

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a database file named .db in my assets folder.
In flutter i have this function to load it:

```
load_names() async {
  databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
  Database database = await _initDB("Questions") as Database;

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> queryResult =
      await database.query('tbl_questions', columns: ['name']);

  await database.close();

  for (Map<String, dynamic> row in queryResult) {
    String address = row['name'];
    tagsList.add(address);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    tagsList.shuffle();
  }
}
```

but it doesn't load in android.
My goal is android

Comment: What has this question to do with SQL?

Comment: the database is in SQL